# Error with POST to page metod and '

Tags: jquery

I am posting data with jquery/ajax. The code itself work good but problem is that I am pasting data from RTE.

```
data: "{ 'gramar':'" + tinyMCE.get('ContentPlaceHolder1_txtGramarNotes').getContent()
```

The problem starts when I want to use ' (example: don't ), it will close 'gramar':' and this will generate error becasue I will have something like this 'gramar':'don't'. I tried .replace("'", "'") but it is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am having a hard time understanding the question, so excuse me if this is not right:

```
data: "{ 'gramar':'" + encodeURIComponent(tinyMCE.get('ContentPlaceHolder1_txtGramarNotes').getContent())}
```

try that. then make sure to url decode on the back end.